# Increasing AIR app stability

Tags: actionscript-3, air, stability

Is there a way to increase the AIR app stability?

I have an app (let's call it a Player) that updates a content inside it every minute. The way it does that — it loads separate SWFs inside itself, fades them in, then out, then unloads. It keeps it outside the Player's application domain. The Player has to run 24/7, but it crashed 148 times during last 5.06 days (~1.2/hour). There's no memory leaks (PCs have 20 GB of RAM) and peaks don't go over 4 GB. It's that heavy because it uses PNG sequences for transitions, each transition consist of 80 separate PNG files (956x2198). We use Quadro K5000 cards to power it. But nothing helps. There's no code errors or anything "wrong" whatsoever.

We're quite out of ideas why it crashes. Are there any tips that may help us out with particular situation? And, after all, is it us, or AIR or the OS?

EDIT 1

---

This is the Event 1001 body from the Event Viewer:

The program Player.exe version 0.0.0.0 stopped interactig with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem in available, check the problem history in Action Center control panel.

Process ID: 1af0

Start Time: 01ce544783aba897

Termination time: 39

Application Path: C:\SomePath\Player.exe

Report Id: %UUID%

Comment: Did you check your system's error log?

Comment: Yeah, I did. And for some reason, nothing is logged.

Comment: No they aren't empty. Updated question body.

Comment: What about the "the problem history in Action Center control panel" then? :)

Comment: Empty. I would have included it.

Comment: I don't have any specific idea but could you also provide the version of AIR you are compiling to?

Comment: AIR SDK is 3.6. I've been doing some profiling lately and here's the stack trace of crash on Mac: http://pastebin.com/CsrR3aDV This happened not automatically, I actually did interact with internal log. But I crashed it after it's been on for ~90 minutes.

Comment: Most likely your app does not free memory properly. Try displaying current memory usage within the app (compile in debug mode for that) and watch closely.

Comment: Weird thought...have you checked for infinite loops? They can be pretty stealthy, and do crash the app. I can't tell you how many times a silent error traced back to that.

Comment: Thanks guys. The profiling goes well. Memory usage appears to be OK. No infinite loop or any other downfalls. And now get ready for the worse — it's been non-crashing for ~6 hours no on my iMac 12 GB RAM. So I'm leaning towards Windows problem. Next version will be compiled with AIR 3.7.

Comment: Compiling with AIR SDK 3.7, enabling debug mode made it to work without crashes. So it's either debug mode or 3.7. Will have to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a lot of alpha channel?
There is a possibility of render crashes after some time, when large transparent bitmaps are used.
Try removing those or at least some of them.